# R: Packrat will not completely uninstall

Tags: r, uninstallation, packrat

I previously turned on packrat() in RStudio. I now wish to completely remove and disable it (i.e. revert to the state prior to installing packrat). I tried to find an option in Rstudio to disable it but could  find anything. I therefore uninstalled R and RStudio by (on OSX 10.9.5) dragging the icons for R and RStudio from the applications folder to the trash. However, upon reinstallation of R (version 3.2.3), the R console displayed the following message and a pop-up prompted me to select a CRAN mirror:

> Packrat is not installed in the local library -- attempting to bootstrap an installation...
>   No source tarball of packrat available locally
>   --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---

So, I found in Library a folder named 'packrat.' After deleting this, I now receive the following upon starting R:

> Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
>
> cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
>     cannot open file 'packrat/init.R': No such file or directory

This is the same error as found in: [Trouble with packrat corrupting R functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339042/trouble-with-packrat-corrupting-r-functioning) yet no .Rprofile or .Rhistory files are found when I search in Finder and I do not know which working directory to search in manually. Can someone advise on how to implement the solution linked above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was indeed that .Rprofile wanted to initialize packrat() on starting R. To fix this, use the below.

## Removing Packrat from .Rprofile

1. Open Terminal
2. Type on a new command line: open ~/.Rprofile
3. Delete the lines related to packrat (these should be clearly labelled because they contain the word packrat)
4. Save the file
5. Restart R/Rstudio