# Problems with Packrat on R

Tags: r, ubuntu, packrat

I have this problem with packrat; When I try to install a random package on R:

"cannot open file 'packrat/init.R': No such file or directory"

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and I tried uninstalling r-base and rStudio

packrat::init() give me errors.

I dont know what to do. I'm thinking in a clean install of my SO. How can I purge packrat? i think this is a bug. Is packrat necessary?

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`packrat` is not a necessary library for most day to day R usage. There are multiple ways to uninstall a package however, for this particular one, I suggest following the instructions from this answer:

[R: Packrat will not completely uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485542/r-packrat-will-not-completely-uninstall)

Comment: And what you think about a clean install of my SO?

Comment: Hopefully, no other changes will be needed after fixing the .RProfile.